# This payment request must be authorized by the sender - Paypal

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Ok, here is what I did:

1. Created a PayRequest
2. SetPaymentOptions - https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/SetPaymentOptions_API_Operation/
3. ExecutePayment - "This payment request must be authorized by the sender". I have ran out of idea on why am I not able to execute the payment. From what I understand, once I execute the payment successfully, I will be given a payKey which I shall use this to redirect user to paypal. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/ExecutePayment_API_Operation/

Attached are the source codes that I used. The values are all hardcoded. I have tried my best to look through at similar questions, and it makes no sense to me as it contradicts what I understand. Some answers were pointing out that the buyer needs to approve the payment first before you executePayment.

I just want to see the details of all items when I reach the paypal login page.

```
//1. Obtain endpoint. For live, no need sandbox?
$endPoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay";

//2. Format the HTTP headers needed to make the call.
$appID = "xxx"; //Sandbox test AppID:
$username = "xxx;
$password = "xxx";
$signature = "xxx";

$paypalHeaders = array(
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID :" . $username,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD :" . $password,
    "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE :" . $signature,
    "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID :" . $appID,
    "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT : JSON",
    "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT : JSON"
);


$data = array();
$data['actionType'] = "CREATE"; //PAY
$data['currencyCode'] = "SGD";
$receiver['amount'] = $orderTotal;
$receiver['email'] = $receiverEmail;
$data['receiverList'] = array();
$data['receiverList']['receiver'][] = $receiver;
$data['returnUrl'] = $returnURL;
$data['cancelUrl'] = $cancleURL;
$requestEnvelope = array();
$requestEnvelope['errorLanguage'] = "en_US";
$data['requestEnvelope'] = $requestEnvelope;

//I omitted the POST call
//print_r($returnedData);
$payKey = $returnedData->payKey;  
$paymentStatus = $returnedData->paymentExecStatus;
```

/*
     *  Set payment options
     */

```
$endPoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/SetPaymentOptions";

//paymentDetailsData
$paymentDetailsData = array();

//set payKey
echo "payKey: " . $payKey;
$paymentDetailsData['payKey'] = $payKey;

//displayOptions
$displayOptions['businessName'] = "My Business";
$paymentDetailsData['displayOptions'] = $displayOptions;

//senderOptions
$senderOptions = array();
$senderOptions['requireShippingAddressSelection'] =  true; //set to true if courier is chosen
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['addresseeName'] = "Ny Name";
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['street1'] = "Address 1Avenue 3";
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['street2'] = "#xx-112";
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['city'] = "Singapore";
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['state'] = "Singapore";
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['zip'] = "123456";
$senderOptions['shippingAddress']['country'] = "Singapore";
$paymentDetailsData['senderOptions'] = $senderOptions;

//item
$item = array();
$item['name'] = "Korea";
$item['itemPrice'] = 11;
//there is still price, and itemcount

//invoiceData
$invoiceData = array();
$invoiceData['item'] = $item;

//receiverOptions
$receiverOptions = array();
$receiverOptions['description'] = "Product description.";
$receiverOptions['invoiceData'] = $invoiceData;

$paypalEmail = "test@test.com"; //I may need to change this
$receiver['email'] = $paypalEmail;
$receiverOptions['receiver'] = $receiver;
$paymentDetailsData['receiverOptions'] = $receiverOptions;

//requestEnvelope. I have set the request envelope above. It is the same. Can still be used.
$paymentDetailsData['requestEnvelope'] = $requestEnvelope;

makePaypalCall($endPoint, $paypalHeaders, $paymentDetailsData);

/*
 * Get payment options. I can see the result of get payment options correctly,
 */
echo "GETTING PAYMENT OPTIONS";
$endPoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/GetPaymentOptions";
$getPaymentData['payKey'] = $payKey;
$getPaymentData['requestEnvelope'] = $requestEnvelope;
makePaypalCall($endPoint, $paypalHeaders, $getPaymentData);

$endPoint = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/ExecutePayment";


/*
 * ExecutePayment. Ok, I get the error here. This payment request must be authorized by the sender
 */
$executePaymentData = array();
echo "paykey: " . $payKey;
$executePaymentData['payKey'] = $payKey;
//$executePaymentData['actionType'] = "PAY";
$executePaymentData['requestEnvelope'] = $requestEnvelope;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand you correctly.

To me it seems like you are skipping the step where the user needs to authorize the payment. When you do a Pay (Create) operation you should see get a RedirectURL in the response from PayPal. You need to redirect the user to this URL for them to authorize the payment on PayPal.

Once they have approved the payment, then you'll be able to execute the payment.

Your steps need to change to:

1. Create PayRequest
2. Set PaymentOptions
3. Redirect to PayPal (RedirectURL from the PayRequest response) for user authorization
4. If authorized, ExecutePayment

PayPal hints at this on [the Pay API operation page](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/)

`URL to redirect the sender's browser to after the sender has logged into PayPal and approved a payment; it is always required but only used if a payment requires explicit approval`

After the step 3, the user will be returned to the URL your provided in `$data['returnUrl'] = $returnURL;`

Comment: I just wanted a simple payment. But with the break down of the purchased items. If I use the "PAY" action method, I cannot set the item details. If I use "CREATE" action method, I need to SetPaymentOptions. I got a reply from PayPal that I don't need to ExecutePayment in my case. But well, payment still not able to go through after I SetPaymentOptions. :(

Comment: Hmm, let me do a couple more tests on my side. I've mostly worked with PayPal's Preapproved payments in the Adaptive Payments API, so the flow you are looking at might be different.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Delayed Chained Payment and often i end up with this error "This payment request must be authorized by the sender". Actually it was due to a   small mistake in the logic.

### wrong procedure (@ step 3)

1. generate a payKey successfully
2. save it to database
3. refresh the page for some reason which results in generating new payKey (this new payKey doesn't update to database)

   ```
   payRequest = pay();
   .....
   if(empty(db_record)) {
     .....
     db_record->payKey = payRequest->payKey;
     db_record->save();
   }
   ```
4. paid with new payKey ( ie. payment approved by sender)
5. trying to execute payment with payKey from database (which is indeed old one. That payKey was not used to make payment)

### Solution

update database with last payKey which used for making payment by getting approval of sender

step 3 should be like

```
    if(empty(db_record) || is_expired(db_record->payKey)) {
      payRequest = pay();
      .....
      .....
      db_record->payKey = payRequest->payKey;
      db_record->save();
    }
```